# Turning a vulgar fraction into numbers in PHP

Tags: php

How to turn a vulgar fraction into something PHP can use to compute the value of.

For example ¾

```
$l = '¾';

echo utf8_encode($l) . ' :: ' .ord($l) . ' :: ' . bin2hex($l) . ' :: ' . chr($l);
```

would output something like this:

`Â¾ :: 194 :: c2be ::`

How can we turn that into 3/4. When the fraction is extracted from a string, the results are different:

```
    $l = '¾ asd';
    $r = utf8_encode($l[0]) . ' :: ' .ord($l[0]) . ' :: ' . bin2hex($l[0]) . ' :: ' . chr($l[0]);
    echo $r;
    echo ' ' ;
    $l = '½ asd';
    $r = utf8_encode($l[0]) . ' :: ' .ord($l[0]) . ' :: ' . bin2hex($l[0]) . ' :: ' . chr($l[0]);
    echo $r;
```

outputs:

`Ã‚ :: 194 :: c2 :: Ã‚ :: 194 :: c2 ::`

Comment: The character `¾` has _nothing_ to do with the numeric value (3/4). This is like asking why "wumpus" does not equal 17.

Comment: `if ($l == '¾') { $l = 3 / 4; }`

Comment: @arkascha thanks for stating the obvious

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use [`iconv()`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.iconv.php) to transliterate the symbol into a form that can then be easily parsed:

```
function utf8FractionToFloat($symbol)
{
    $translit = trim(iconv('UTF-8', 'ASCII//TRANSLIT', $symbol));

    if ($translit && preg_match('~^(\d+)/(\d+)$~', $translit, $match)) {
        return $match[1] / $match[2];
    }
}

var_dump(utf8FractionToFloat('½')); // float(0.5)
var_dump(utf8FractionToFloat('¾')); // float(0.75)
```

Comment: How can I extract the vulgar fraction from a string to use with this method? $l = '½ asd'; substr($l,0,1); or $l[0]; does not equate to the fraction part of the string?

Comment: `$l` -> `$symbol`, but otherwise this is fantastic

Comment: mb_substr() to the rescue, thanks for your help, all working perfectly now

Comment: @iainn Thanks, fixed it.